# How to change background colour of individual list items of a nested list upon hover (and to full menu width)

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type='text/css'  media='all'>
        #menu {width: 50%;}
        .high {background: #0F0;}
        .list-item :hover {background: #000;}

        /* non essential styles */
        .list-item a{text-decoration: none;}
        .list-item :hover a{color: #FFF;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu" >
        <ul>
            <li class="list-item">
                <div class="level-0 high" id="P0">
                    <a href="#">P0</a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <div class="level-1" id="C0-P0">
                            <a href="#">C0-P0</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <div class="level-1" id="C1-P0">
                            <a href="#">C1-P0</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
                <div class="level-0" id="P1">
                    <a href="#">P1</a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <div class="level-1" id="C0-P1">
                            <a href="#">C0-P1</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <div class="level-1" id="C1-P1">
                            <a href="#">C1-P1</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Structure:
P0
__ C0-P0
__ C1-P0
P1
__ C0-P1
__ C1-P1

Currently I am unable to select and change background (upon hover) of Child items individually.
However if I try to use `first-child` selectors - I am able to select each list item individually. But -
then the parent's selections are limited to only the anchor width and not the full menu width.

Here's the [JSFilldle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj13/4FZsa/)

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4S7fD/ however, I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: try `.list-item div:hover` http://jsfiddle.net/4FZsa/1/

Comment: Thanks - I had tried this but had left a space after `div`.
@Yoshi please place this in answer so that this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
.list-item :hover {background: #000;}
```

to this:

```
li .list-item :hover {background: #000;}
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgHZ6/3/)...

Comment: and now `P0` & `P1` is not select-able.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're asking but there should not be a space between `:hover` and the element.

It should be `.list-item:hover {...}` not `.list-item :hover {...}`